# New PC build not booting - fans don't run

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, fan, computer-building

PC part list https://au.pcpartpicker.com/list/yTZKRG

Here is the problem I run into: I installed the CPU, 1 stick of RAM, the heatsink, connected the fans to the board, connected power supply to the motherboard and CPU.

When I turn on the switch in power supply, the motherboard started blinking blue LEDs. I turn on the motherboard, it keeps blinking for a few seconds, then turn itself off, then turn back on and starts blinking again. Fans are not running, and nothing happen after that.

I'm just wondering if there is anything that I missed. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like bent socket pins and/or bad CPU.  It's also possible your motherboard doesn't support your CPU.  It's also possible the CPU is overheating, which can happen faster then the system can POST, if not cooling is happening at all.  If the fans are not turning on, that's likely, diagnosis the reason the heatsink fan isn't turning on

Comment: @Ramhound the CPU is not overheating, as right after that I removed the heatsink to investigate, the CPU is ice cold, no bent pins as far as I know

Comment: if the system isn't POSTing then it's a hardware problem

Comment: @SDsolar Wild guesses are not considered answers.  It's impossible for me to "flesh then out" due to the broadness of the question

Comment: @Ramhound which hardware do you think is malfunctioned, I can send them back to the retailer and get new ones since I just bought them

Comment: I already shared all my thoughts on this matter I have nothing else to add

Comment: Do you have any space PSU to check if its not a power supply that causes this problem? Also it could be bent mobo pins.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the motherboard out of the case to check to see if your not having a short on the board from the case itself. Since you're not fully booting the computer, prior to POST you don't even seem to get a noise or a POST code, it points to that.